# Serverless frameworks CORS failing to deploy to AWS CloudFormation

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

Any idea on how to fix this issue deploying to AWS with Serverless Cors flag?

Added the cors flag to serverless.yml of an existing endpoint as specified in the [Serverless guide](https://www.serverless.com/blog/cors-api-gateway-survival-guide)

```
  get-connections-by-account:
    name: ${self:custom.stackName}-getConnectionsByAccount
    handler: src/functions/get_connections_by_account.default
    events:
      - http:
          method: get
          cors: true
          path: /account/{accountReference}/connections
          request:
            parameters:
              paths:
                - accountReference
```

It works fine when deploy locally with Serverless+Terraform+Localstack but when deploy to AWS with Terraform get

> Method already exists for this resource (Service: AmazonApiGateway;
> Status Code: 409; Error Code: ConflictException; Request ID:
> ea4b3ea8-eb62-4314-ac92-993b617a575f; Proxy: null)

[image: and then the rollback]

Comment: What version of terraform-aws-provider are you using? The recent 4.0.0 release had some breaking changes around bucket features like CORS.

Comment: terraform -version gives me Terraform v0.14.6

Comment: A provider is more like a terraform library. I'm not super familiar with the serverless/terraform/localstack stack. Do you write your own .tf files? Is there a block in there with the title `provider "aws"` or something similar?

Comment: Missed the "provider" bit; in my terraform.tf have: provider "aws" { version = "~> 2.44" }

Answer (score 1):

A colleague pointed out that someone had added manually (from AWS Console) the OPTIONS method to the endpoint

[image: Options API Gateway added]

Removing the OPTIONS method fixed the problem

Comment: ClickOps for the win. :')